# View() vs. PartialView()

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The `View()` method can load Partial Views.

Is the difference between `View()` and `PartialView()` is that `View()` can load views and partial views and `PartialView()` can only load partial views?

Comment: is this a tongue-twister?

Comment: @Lorenzo How many Views would a PartialView view if a PartialView could view Views?  Please be impartial, I'd like to get your view: will a PartialView view Views or is it just a View that's partial to a Partial?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It's up to a view engine to decide if they want to treat partial views different from regular views.

For example, in the WebFormViewEngine there is no difference.

In the new ASP.NET MVC 3 RazorViewEngine there are some differences. Only regular views will have the "_viewstart.cshtml" pages run because they are meant for things such as setting up layout pages.

Comment: Viewstart support and layout support (Separately) plus minor exception differences: http://completedevelopment.blogspot.com/2014/01/is-there-really-no-difference-between.html

Comment: In addition I think `PartialView()` will look for views locations of which are specified in PartialViewLocationFormats property of your ViewEngine and `View()` will use `ViewLocationFormats` property.

Comment: @MaksimVi. that is correct except that in MVC's default view engines the locations are all identical between Partial views and "Regular" views. But if you configured them differently or are using a different view engine they could certainly be different.

Answer (score 32):

I think the biggest difference is about the use of the `_Layout` page:

- **PartialView()**: the razor engine will get the view (e.g. index.cshtml) without any layout page (_layout.cshtml).
- **View()**: the engine will get your view (e.g. index.cshtml) and then appends the content of this view inside the layout page (_layout.cshtml)

Comment: +1 because this is IMO really the most important fact! Try to use e.g. `@Html.Action("SideMenu", "Menu")` this way: `public ActionResult SideMenu() { return View(); }`. You will be wondering why is it renderend into `_Layout` with `RenderBody()`. Return `PartialView()` instead because it is not rendered via `RenderBody()` to `_Layout`.

Answer (score 3):

If you have `Index.aspx` and `Index.ascx` for the same controller having both methods might help disambiguate. But I agree that in general `View` is more commonly used. And `PartialView` can also be used to load full views, it's just that it's semantically wrong.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the WebFormViewEngine uses the exact same file extensions for both regular views and partial views, so that probably won't help you disambiguate.

Comment: Eilon is incorrect. Partial views are .ascx and views are .aspx

Comment: @Chevex If you look at WebFormViewEngine's `ViewLocationFormats` and `PartialViewLocationFormats` collections you will see that they are identical. While the convetion is to use .aspx for full views and .ascx for partial views, the view engine treats them the same.