# ASP.NET MVC Show View after Ajax call to a Controller

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, jquery, razor, json

I have a View with a submit form: when I click it a jquery/ajax function is called. This function has to encode the View Model, call a Controller action and show the View returned.
Now, this is my function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Analyze() {
    var urlact = '@Url.Action("Analysis")';
    var model = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))';
    $.ajax({
        data: model,
        type: "POST",
        url: urlact,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            //WHAT HERE??
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

And the *Analysis* action is a kind of

```
public ViewResult Analysis(IEnumerable<Azienda> aziende) {
        Debug.WriteLine(aziende.Count());
        return View(aziende);
    }
```

Returning a View!
How can I display that View on success:function(data)?
I tried changing dataType to *html* and calling on success **alert(data)** but I had problems with the encoded model, I tried commenting the contentType line but same model-encoding issue.

Does someone know how to do that?
A js/query/ajax workaround-trick is fine, too.

Thanks you all!

Comment: Do you want to replace the whole page or just part of it?

Comment: I want to replace all the page!

Comment: Why not just a regular submit on the form then ?

Comment: Because that causes a postback and a page refresh

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?  I want to do something similar

Comment: Hi , it will be great if you could share how did you work around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
return PartialView()
```

instead of

```
return View()
```

in your controller. Then in the success function in your ajax call, use the jQuery .html() function to update the element you wish to update in your html. See [Query.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) and [View() vs. PartialView()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210138/view-vs-partialview)

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate partial view with aziende as its model and return this in your Analysis action and then append the result to a div in your view:

```
//action returning a partial view
public ActionResult Analysis(IEnumerable<Azienda> aziende) 
{
    Debug.WriteLine(aziende.Count());
    return PartialView("_partialView", aziende);
}

//then append the result to a div in your javascript
success: function (data) {
    $("#some-div").html(data); 
}
```