# Bootstrap-Modal Pop-Up Design Issue With Page Header

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to pop up with bootstrap. In my "NoteListPartial.cshtml" page; if I click on the edit button, I want the "Not.cshtml" to be opened with pop up. But when I click button pop-up appear but my header appear too with pop-up but I don't want it to be.

1- I call NoteListPartial.cshtml page on the Detail.cshtml page.

2- My Detail.cshtml code is as follows:

```
<div class="NoteList">

</div

<script>
    var projectid = @Model.ID;
    $.ajax({
        method: "get",
        url: '@Url.Action("NoteListPartial", "Project")',
        data: {projectid:projectid},
        success: function(returningdata){
            $("div.NoteList").html(returningdata);
        }
    });
</script>
```

3- And my NoteListPartial.cshtml code is as follows:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="item">
        <div class="item-head">
            <div class="item-details">
                <a class="item-name primary-link">@item.Name</a>
                span class="item-status">
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Note", "Project", new { ID = item.ID, ProjectID = item.ProjectID })" data-target="#NoteDetailModal" data-toggle="modal">EDIT</a>
                    <a href="@Url.Action("NoteDelete", "Project",new { ID=item.ID, ProjectID=item.ProjectID})">Delete</a>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item-body"> @item.Content </div>
    </div>
}

<div class="modal fade" id="NoteDetailModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- Content comes here. This code continues at Note.cshtml -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

4- And my Note.cshtml code is as follows and **I want the "Not.cshtml" to be opened with pop up**:

```
<!-- Continuation of modal on page NoteListPartial.cshtml -->

<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dissmiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">x</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit Note</h4>
</div>
<form method="post" role="form">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Title:</label>
            <input type="text" name="Name" value="@Model.Name" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Content:</label>
            <textarea name="Content">@Model.Content</textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Update" />
    </div>
</form>
```

When I run the project and click edit button in the Detail.cshtml, pop-up is opening but I am encountering such a screen:
[image]

ProjectController.cs:

```
public ActionResult NoteListPartial(RaporModel Filter, int? ProjectID)
{
    IEnumerable<tbl_ProjectNote> prjnote = Sabitler.Note.Where(d => d.ProjectID == ProjectID).OrderByDescending(d => d.ID);
    int PageNo = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["Page"] ?? "1");
    int totalnumber = prjnote.Count();
    prjnote = prjnote.Skip((PageNo - 1) * Filter.SBGS).Take(Filter.SBGS);
    ViewBag.Pagination = Functions.PageToGet(PageNo, totalnumber, Filter.SBGS, "", "active");
    return PartialView(prjnote.ToList());
}

public ActionResult Note(RaporModel Filter, int? ID)
{
var prjnote = db.tbl_ProjectNot.FirstOrDefault(d => d.ID == ID);
if (prjnote == null)
    prjnote = new tbl_ProjectNot();
    return View(prjnote);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Note(tbl_ProjectNote prjnote)
{
    if (prjnote.Name == null)
    {
        BilgiMesaji(Tur.Warn, "Note title can't null!");
        return RedirectToAction("Note", new { ProjectID = prjnote.ProjectID });
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(prjnote.Name) && prjnote.Name.Length > 100)
    {
        BilgiMesaji(Tur.Warn, "Note title can not be more than 100 characters!");
        return RedirectToAction("Note", new { ProjectID = prjnote.ProjectID });
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(prjnote.Content) && prjnote.Content.Length > 500)
    {
        BilgiMesaji(Tur.Warn, "Note content can not be more than 500 characters!");
        return RedirectToAction("Note", new { ProjectID = prjnote.ProjectID });
    }

    var prjnoteDB = db.tbl_ProjectNote.FirstOrDefault(d => d.ID == prjnote.ID);

    if (prjnoteDB == null)
        prjnoteDB = new tbl_ProjectNot();

        prjnoteDB.Name = prjnote.Name;
        prjnoteDB.Content = prjnote.Content;
        prjnoteDB.ProjectID = prjnote.ProjectID;
        if (prjnoteDB.ID == 0)
        {
            prjnoteDB.UserID = us.ID;
            prjnoteDB.AddDate = DateTime.Now;
            db.tbl_ProjectNot.Add(prjnoteDB);
        }
        db.SaveChanges();

        Sabitler.Note = db.tbl_ProjectNot.ToList();

        BilgiMesaji(Tur.Success, "Recording successfully added!");

        return RedirectToAction("Note", new { ProjectID = prjnote.ProjecID });
}
```

Comment: Could you show the controller code that returns your "NoteListPartial" View please.

Comment: Yes, of course. I am adding the code now.

Comment: I add. Can you check please?

Comment: And for "Note" too?

Comment: try `@{
    Layout = null;
}` it seems like `Layout` page has been render with Partial view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return with a PartialView not View in the `public ActionResult Note(RaporModel Filter, int? ID)` action:

```
public ActionResult Note(RaporModel Filter, int? ID)
{
    var prjnote = db.tbl_ProjectNot.FirstOrDefault(d => d.ID == ID);
    if (prjnote == null)
        prjnote = new tbl_ProjectNot();
    return PartialView(prjnote);
}
```

Returning View() will include the _layout.cshtml page that has your header and navigation bar.

For more information see here:
[View() vs. PartialView()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210138/view-vs-partialview)